# Simple delete query based on variable

Tags: php, sql

I want to delete the record when the id column is equal to $id. Would this work?

```
$query = "DELETE FROM $TableName WHERE id=$id";
```

As a side i also want to set the number of rows that can be deleted to a
limit of 1.  I know i have to use limit but i am unsure on its parameters

Comment: did you tried to delete the record? try to use a begin tran to go safe on that before

Comment: Are you using MySQL? Postgres?

Comment: If you only want to delete 1 record, how do you know which one to delete?

Comment: Yes i am using mysql and @Zinov I dont know what you mean

Comment: You should be sure that your id is unique, the best way would be to have it as a primary key of your table. Then you can omit the limit. And yes, it should work.

Comment: essentially in the table you have for example 
1-apple
2-pear
3-banana

i want to delete apple if the admin clicks on 1

Comment: isn't your id already unique?

Comment: IT WORKS THANK YOU EVERYONE

Comment: .........err, huh?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You could do

```
mysqli_query = ($con, "DELETE FROM `$TableName` WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
```

That should do it exactly my friend

Comment: Can you mark this as the right answer; that would mean alot to me

Comment: `DELETE FROM '$TableName'` that will **not** work; I can assure you of that.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)